# How to emulate onLowMemory()?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have put some instructions in onLowMemory() callback and want to test the same. Is there a "direct" way to test onLowMemory function of the application subclass?

Or will I have to just overload the phone by starting many apps and doing memory intensive tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce the amount of ram available in the emulator.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html#hardwareopts